# Actual Materials - ITEM List

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Working on Anywhere (7.5.2.0) Work execution app. After adding an item in Actual Materials, it is displaying in the Anywhere list but data not showing in Maximo Asset Management - Actual Materials tab. what is the issue ? How to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

Please install our latest fixpack 7.5.2.2, there are a few fixes in this area included.  It also includes has a transaction logger (under the main Logging screen in the app) where you can watch the transactions that are being sent to and downloaded from the server and help diagnose these issues.